# Please help me Filtering out Third Party Logging for Apache Log4j in my Java Application

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using Third Party jars which are appending their own logs in my Java Application's Log file , I don't want to append those third party logs in my log file as it makes log file very clumsy and confusing.

I know this method, log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=OFF to turn off the logging in this particular package org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate in my lo4j.properties, but the problem is I have many such jars added in my application and hence , want to avoid writing manually for each package associated with the jar.

Also if any new jars are added again I have to append this configuration in my log4j.properties file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can takedown whole librabries as in

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF
```

or you can turn off logging for the root logger itself and enable it for classes/packages of your interest

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
log4j.logger.com.your-package=DEBUG, yourappender
```

this will enable DEBUG logging for all subpackages and classes under `com.your-package`

look at Logging Hierarchies at [Log4j intro](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Comment: my pleasure, you might also accept the answer so that others can know it does work

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else still stumped by this, I was using spring 4 with log4j2. Spring 4 seems to only check for log4j, not log4j2.xml.

I added a log4j.xml file (as well as log4j2.xml) to my resources and that worked for me.

Hope it helps someone else