# BeanDeserializer Warnings: How to get rid of them?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, polarion

I have a Java application which is using the a SOAP API of a software (Polarion) and I get warnings of BeanDeserializer (whatever that is)
which I want to suppress because they flood my logfile but have no known impact.

So I get warnings like

> [WARN] BeanDeserializer - Invalid element in
>   com.polarion.alm.ws.client.types.tracker.WorkItem -
>   linkedOslcResources

but I can't figure out what this means.

Based on the provided info [in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090243/how-to-solve-saxexception-invalid-element-in) I concluded that these Warning occur due to an outdated axis library (I currently use axis-1.4.jar). I used an updated version [from this source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadaxis2161jar.htm), imported the .jar and removed the former one but the suddenly there errors all over the place so I restored my lib folder to having only the axis-1.4.jar.

The apache page does not provide a download of a .JAR of [a newer axis version](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html) and the [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis) says 1.4 is the latest one.

And now I am out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried this  [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949856/please-help-me-filtering-out-third-party-logging-for-apache-log4j-in-my-java-app)

[or]  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396086/hide-third-party-jar-logs-from-logback-or-properties-file)

Comment: How are you building your code and managing the dependencies on the external libraries like axis?  Do you have a maven pom.xml you can share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the log level for that package/class to OFF to get rid of the messages but I would suggest using ERROR so you can still identify errors if they occur